# Misconceptions about electric theory

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, education

[Electric misconceptions](http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html)

This is a fairly big question, and is divided into three parts. One part is a separate question.

The site lists several common misconceptions, and what the correct way of things really are, but doesn't list any references.

### **Q1. Is what is written on the site correct?**

I quoted in the 7 "main misconceptions" from the site, and also brought another one from it that I found interesting. The quotes are shortened down, to not take up too much space. ***I recommend going to the site and read it.***

> **All electric currents are flows of electrons?** Wrong.
>
> Electric currents are not always flows of electrons, they are flows of any type
>   of electric charge. Both protons and electrons possess exactly the
>   same amount of 'electricity.'[1](http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html)
>
> **"Electricity" is made of electrons, not protons?** Nope.
>
> Charges of "electricity" are carried both by electrons and protons.[1](http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html)
>
> **Electrons are a kind of energy particle?** Wrong.
>
> Electrons and protons are matter, not energy.[1](http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html)
>
> **"Electricity" carries zero mass because electrons have little mass?** No.
>
> Quantities of "Electricity" (meaning charge) have weight because
>   charge is part of matter particles.[1](http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html)
>
> **Positive charge is really just a loss of electrons?** Wrong.
>
> Positive charge is not made of "missing electrons." Positive charge is
>   a genuine type of charge in its own right.[1](http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html)
>
> **Positive charge cannot flow?** Totally wrong.
>
> Electric currents in a metal wire are flows of electrons, but in many
>   other materials both the positive and negative charges can flow.[1](http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html)
>
> **To create "static" charge, we transfer the electrons?** Not always.
>
> "Static" or imbalanced charges can be created by removing electrons
>   from a neutral atom.[1](http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html)
>
> **THE "ELECTRICITY" INSIDE OF WIRES MOVES AT THE SPEED OF LIGHT?** Wrong.
>
> In metals, electric current is a flow of electrons. Many books claim that these electrons flow at the speed of light. This is incorrect. Electrons in an electric current actually flow quite slowly, at speeds on the order of centimeters per minute. [1](http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html)

First part of the question is just trustworthiness of the page. Second part is about the teaching. Teaching is tricky, and what the page goes against is teaching misconceptions to kids in school, which then stick till when they are older, and they struggle to learn the right things, because they was taught wrong to begin with.

### **Q2. Is teaching misconceptions a bad idea or is it unavoidable?**

Third part of the question is too big to include here, I will provide a link to its own question.
The third part is about how spread out the misconcepts are, how commonly they are taught. It's a too big question to have here, so take that part over to that question.

### **Q3. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15855/how-spread-out-are-the-misconceptions-about-electric-theory**

Edit the third part of the question is deleted, it was not very interesting afterall.

Comment: The question seems unanswerable to me, as it is unclear what is "completely off". It is common a simplification is seen as "completely off" by those having a deeper understanding. Moreover, it is unclear to me whether the schools really teach "All electric currents are flows of electrons" or rather "most often electric currents are flows of electrons". Most likely this will differ country to country, school to school and teacher to teacher. Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current speaks about flow of charge in general.

Comment: You might get other perspectives if you post it here also - http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ Suma The bolded part, is where I made the question more clear. The title is just a title, and it is hard to make it work as question without context. I bolded the main question, because it usually catches peoples eyes.

Comment: @davidblaine good idea. The question is fit for Skeptics, but the expertise on the topic is elsewhere.

Comment: @Suma because the flow of charge can be considered either direction depending on your perspective. If I recall correctly it is general convention that we consider the current flowing in the opposite direction of electron movement, but not a rule.

Comment: @Wertilq - Please post the link to the question if you post it on the electronics website. I too really wanted to know if bill beaty's arguments and claims are valid or not. I am not too sure about them. If they were really that good, he probably would have been noticed and credited by books, blogs, academia etc.

Comment: So far as I can tell, what the page says is consistent with what I was taught, it is also correct that we are (at least initially) taught a simplified view that leads to many common misconceptions (e.g. it is commonplace to say capacitors store charge when in fact they don't, they store energy). It doesn't mean that what is taught is "completely off" just that what is taught is a useful but simplified view and uses commonplace terms like electricity and charge whose ordinary meanings are ambiguous. Alas I don't know of a good reference for all this.

Comment: @davidblaine http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/65229/how-correct-is-electric-theory-taught-in-school http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60750/how-correct-is-electric-theory-taught-in-school The thing is though, I aim to bring the experts here, to have this as the main answer. I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but well it's done.

Comment: *`If they were really that good, he probably would have been noticed and credited by books, blogs, academia etc.`* Nothing ground-breaking, he is just ranting on stuff that is true in a misleading way.

Comment: @davidblaine Overall is the question treated with hostility in electrics, and in physics the interest of the question is low.

Comment: Is K-6 the six grade, as in 11-13 year old kids?

Comment: Kindergarten to 6th grade is how I interpretted it.

Comment: The source [explicitly defines](http://amasci.com/miscon/k6.txt) it: 5-11, inclusive.

Comment: This question needs some serious work to make it answerable. If the question is "Are the explanations given technically correct?", how about we cut it back to 1 or 2 to make it manageable? If the question is "Are students really taught these falsehoods?", how about we restrict it to a smaller region and period of time, or else it is unanswerable. But the *real* question is "Is it unreasonable to simplify physics to make it intelligible for pre-pubescents?" The effectiveness and morality of [Wittgenstein's Ladder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children) is off-topic here.

Comment: I feel it's kind of like saying *"Newtonian physics though in school are wrong, because they don't mention relativistic effects"*.

Comment: @Oddthinking yea, considering how people react to the question, I agree with it. I kinda ask several things(some things inbetween the lines as well), I make several claims, related to electric theory, and I also pull in locality to things, turning it all into a big mess. I kinda had several questions about one thing, and it shows, looking in hind sight. First question is "Is what is written on the site trustworthy and true?", Second is "Are the oversimplified version taught commonly in school?", Third question is "Is lying a correct way to handle over-complicating things?"

Comment: @Oddthinking How do you suggest I proceed with this? Should I turn this question into "Is what written on this site trustworthy and true?" And then make another question for the other two subquestions?

Comment: I don't want to defend science education (in the US, where I know something about it) much as I think it could use much improvement, but ... Teaching this stuff to kids in a way that is (1) useful to them in making judgements about the world, (2) systematic and (3) prepares them for more rigorous treatments later is *hard*. Demanding that they cover all the cases and never say anything that is not completely correct is just plain silly. You could probably do that with the brightest of the bright but you *will* simply confuse most of the class.

Comment: Matter is a form of energy, though that kind of energy (the mass of the electron) is not exploited in electricity, but rather the energy stored as the potential of a charged particle in an electric field. Still, it is wrong to claim that matter isn't energy.

Comment: Indeed, a flow of protons can take place, and we don't need a high temperature plasma for that either: just H+ ions in an aqueous solution that is energized by electric probes.

Comment: To make answers more plausible you really may want to make a post per claim. Trying to refute this many requires very very long answers to also have references.

Comment: @Kortuk I will do that either tomorrow or during weekend, but I will probably have to spend some time then, to think on things clearly and make a clear question, to avoid what happened in my first try. It'll probably take a while.

Comment: Relevant: [Physics.SE: Why is the charge naming convention wrong?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/17131/176)

Comment: Without citing specific sources, like textbooks or lecture notes from particular schools, the argument that electricity is taught badly is simply laughable. High schoolers with a rounded science background that includes chemistry as well as physics will know about things like half-cell reactions, and movements of positive ions which balance negative ones moving the other way. In high school, at various times, I covered subjects such as the [Nernst equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst_equation), and [Faraday's Law of induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction).

Comment: given that the explanations as to how some at least of the statements are wrong are themselves wrong, I'd say the claimant here is in need of his own education... Electricity is neither the flow of electrons OR protons, but the flow of energy (which happens at rates far exceeding those of the electrons or protons carrying that charge) for example.

Comment: This whole thread reminds me of the time I ran into the first couple of volumes of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_of_Theoretical_Physics .  The mechanics one starts with the principle of least action and derives Newtonian mechanics from it, and the fields one starts with "suppose there's a four dimensional vector field..." and derives relativistic electromagnetism from that.  I was stunned; really made me realize how much my physics education until then had more or less followed the history of physics.  But I'm still glad I was gotten started with F=ma rather than Maupertuis’ Principle!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Author here.

Is all that stuff correct?  Certainly.  It comes right out of physics texts and this list has been discussed by educators (mostly on PHYS-L, in the net's early days.)  For many years I was updating it with numerous slight corrections.

If you find that the material conflicts with what you were taught  ...then there's a problem.

That list of common misconceptions was collected from numerous sources, including textbooks, pop articles, and many adult experts (electrical engineers on many forums.)  It's not only a list of K-6 textbook problems, since the same problems appear in the general public's understanding of Electricity.  The article grew out of a central question during my exhibits design work at Museum of Science in Boston:  how should we teach "electricity" in our new exhibit?   The K-6 texts we inspected were full of basic factual errors as well as misleading oversimplifications, so we couldn't use them as a basis for teaching.  Our goal became: explain classic E&M to little kids and grandparents, but done in a way so as not to breed the numerous barriers which halt further learning.   (See "Textbooks Flunk Out", 1999 Boston Globe http://virus.lucifer.com/virus.2Q99/1096.html)

And yes, non-electron currents are common: that's how nerves work, that's how electric currents can exist in dirt and in oceans, and exclusively proton currents are common in battery electrolyte (where they're usually called positive hydrogen ions.)  It's a widespread misconception that "electric current" means "electron flow" and nothing else.   Perhaps if we were only teaching future repair technicians, then it might be acceptable to avoid non-metal conductors while pretending that all currents were electron flows.  But kids who are future engineers and scientists need a wider understanding.   (Me, I think the general public would love such a wider understanding.)

Yes, it's acceptable to teach "lies to children," as long as those simplifications don't lead to persistent misconceptions and learning-barriers.   E.g. atoms are like little solar systems with electrons orbiting the nucleus?  No problem.  Those simplifications get updated later, so they're far more useful than harmful.  Chemistry techs don't angrily resist the QM concepts of orbitals/clouds, and forever after cling tenaciously to the solar-system model over the rest of their careers.  But in electronics, such things are common.  The serious problems arise when those oversimplified concepts are never questioned, and they become long-lasting learning barriers which persist into adulthood.

Is this all something new?   No, the list was from the late 1980s, and the deeper issue of textbook errors is a major decades-long problem and still being battled by hundreds of people, see for example http://www.textbookleague.org/ttlindex.htm.   Even Richard Feynman brings it up in "Judging Books By Their Covers." http://www.textbookleague.org/103feyn.htm  Note that Feynman found he could make no headway, and had to give up.  That should tell us something.

Are the listed misconceptions an unavoidable consequence of simplifying E&M physics for children?  Definitely not, and since I wrote my articles, several grade-school textbooks have appeared which completely avoid the mistakes.  A few publishers actually listened to the critics and made major changes.  That, or the critics themselves authored new books.

By explaining EM physics at the grade-school level while removing all the typical misleading/wrong explanations, these texts demonstrate that the concepts involved *aren't* overly sophisticated or fit only for college level.  They demonstrate that the problems in earlier books were genuine errors easily removed.  And obviously they show that an entire community is working on this problem, not just me alone.  And so, more references...

1. MS Steinberg's C.A.S.T.L.E. electricity curriculum.  This was the end result of a 1980s project to redesign high-school material to treat the known student electricity misconceptions via direct hands-on experiments using supercapacitors, bulbs, and hand-crank DC generators.  http://www.ptec.org/items/detail.cfm?ID=4438
2. Smithsonian/National Academies 2002 "Electrical Energy and Circuit Design."  The authors built an entire middle-school electricity curriculum from scratch, and avoided every single problem on my list, even including the separate 'static electricity' list.  [http://www.amazon.com/Electrical-~Science-Technology-Concepts-schools~/dp/0892788968](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0892788968)
3. Prentice Hall's 2007 "Science Explorer" series, "Electricity and Magnetism."  Again, no misconceptions from my list.  This text is by Dr. C Wainwright of the "castle" capacitor project.  [http://www.amazon.com/Electricity-Magnetism-Ph-D-Camille-Wainwright/dp/0133651150](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133651150)
4. G. McWhorter's 1987 "Basic Electricity JE-101," Radio Shack.  An electrical engineer simplifies E&M physics while avoiding all the "infectious misconceptions."  Interesting that he apparently did this independently before the rise of electricity-misconceptions research, and of course long before I was able to post my own work online.
   [http://www.amazon.com/Electricity-JE-101-Science-Junior-Engineering/dp/B00071OWRE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00071OWRE)

Note that except for Prentice-Hall, the major K-12 education publishers haven't followed suit.  To find this 'repaired' curriculum material, a school district has to obtain their products from outside the conventional channels.

What about all the engineering students who acquired a headful of misconceptions in grade school?  Darren Ashby is now (2005) selling a "textbook" which carefully goes through point-by-point and repairs all the damage.  So, now I won't have to write one myself!  "Electrical Engineering 101: Everything You Should Have Learned in School...but Probably Didn't"  [http://www.amazon.com/Electrical-Engineering-101-Third-School-but/dp/0123860016](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123860016)

And don't miss that 2002 Sefton paper:

Understanding Electricity and Circuits: What the Text Books Don’t Tell You
http://science.uniserve.edu.au/school/curric/stage6/phys/stw2002/sefton.pdf

Comment: Yes I am aware of what I was taught was a bit lacking, the article fascinated me and piqued my interest. I read it fairly long time ago, and at that time I thought "Is this really true?". A problem I see is that with the claim "textbooks are wrong", and then you said reason your article is correct is because it's from physics text. It's word against word, and without being really experienced in electronics, it's hard to ground the claim. Also a bit of a problem with my question is that currently, is like 3 questions, I will probably to divide it into several.

Comment: Also thank you for taking your time answering the question. How did you come across it? I posted it like yesterday, and you seem to be new to Skeptics.

Comment: To clarify:  I find that college-level textbooks have only few errors/misconceptions.   It's the grade-school texts (and articles aimed at the general public) which contain the drek.   And, how did I find this thread!  Sorcery!   (I ego-surf by watching the list of referring pages on my site traffic http://www.sitemeter.com/?a=stats&s=s50wbeaty&r=11)  I find the best sites that way, plus occasional conversations about mine.  I guess I could figure out how to parse the Apache logs for eskimo.com, so I could strip out all the incoming google stuff seen in that list.

Comment: Oh also:  to cut through bs, if someone insists that my articles are wrong, just have them point out the details.  Perhaps they'll discover something I need to repair.  But that happens less and less, and most often they'll only demonstrate that they have the very misconceptions I'm complaining about.

Comment: @wbeaty Welcome to Skeptics, hope you stick around. :) One thing that we really like here is substantiation of claims and answers.  I read through your answer, and found it to be a great answer.  Just wondering if you could reference some of the key source material from your research. That way it doesn't appear so much as either original research or an opinion answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Good point, I'll go add obvious links to my reference page on misconceptions: http://amasci.com/miscon/electref.html.    For the curious, good intro papers online are Sefton 2002: http://science.uniserve.edu.au/school/curric/stage6/phys/stw2002/sefton.pdf, and Chabay/Sherwood 1999: http://www.matterandinteractions.org/Content/Articles/circuit.pdf.  If you're more serious, get hold of the 1985 conf. proceedings 'Aspects of Understanding Electricity.'  For kids' naive physics concepts (not textbook-taught errors,) AIP/OP compiled this list: http://amasci.com/miscon/opphys.html

Comment: I liked this answer the most, but it's still not perfect. It's lacking in references to correctness. I can subjectively and as a person accept correctness of the site, since it's old, and you say you have updated it, with feedback from people in the field, and that many people that have read it said it's correct. Objectively for making a good answer to the question, I need more references though.

Answer (score 10):

No. We are talking here about 5-13 years old kids. The concepts that the source talks about are very sophisticated. When we are talking about little children, a level of simplification is needed. I studied (now finishing) a double degree in Physics, and Electrical Eng. and what I've seen is that even in undergraduate and graduate courses in the university, courses that are intended to Electrical or Software Engineers often simplify the physics involved ,to a degree that wouldn't be in physics courses, for better understanding of the general more important principal. For example, you don't need to learn quantum physics, only to know that an electron can only be in discrete levels in an atom.

I'll touch on the 8 claims that you provide here.

Some of the claims that the source makes are plain false. For example, the first and the "static charge" statements. Other statements that the source "falsifies" are right inside a solid materials, and others are right inside metal, since semiconductors, plasma, and Ion currents are quite complicated materials, and that children don't often get to see plasma streams or semiconductors, but most of them associate electricity only with electric wires and maybe simple electric instruments, like light bulbs switches and ovens it's safe to assume that when you talk about electricity to children, even if you don't state so explicitly, you are assuming current inside metal conductors.

Lets look over the statements provided here, and see if they are right. My sources is what I was taught during my physics Bsc. For references you can see the book that was the course book when I studies the basics of Electricity and Magnetism, [Electricity and Magnetism from Berkley](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070049084), or you can watch the [course filmed at MIT by Professor Walter Lewin](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-02-electricity-and-magnetism-spring-2002/video-lectures/). Some of the answer include some complex material from more advanced courses or subjects, at the end I'll give a list of the books which were the course books when I took those subjects.

> All electric currents are flows of electrons?

Yes, they are. There is the concept of positive charge flow, where the charge carriers are holes, however, at the micro level, it is still a flow of electrons, on the opposite side that creates a lack of electrons which "moves". However this is **NOT** intro level physics, but taught at solid state courses or semiconductors courses. Just to clarify, holes are positive charge carriers, however, holes are not a real particle, they are a representation of a lack of electrons.

**EDIT**: after consulting a physics professor and doing some more research into this, I realize I was wrong here. Here is the fixed version:
Protons are ionized hydrogen atoms,  Ion conductance is present in [Plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_%28physics%29), liquids, and can be present in some solids. But this isn't present in metals and wires, or any "classic" electrical appliance. since we assume that we are talking to a 13 years old kid, we don't talk about plasma, neurotransmitters, or semiconductors, so yes, inside a metal wire all electric current is due to the displacement of electrons.*

> "Electricity" is made of electrons, not protons? Nope.
>
> Charges of "electricity" are carried both by electrons and protons

Not sure what "Electricity is made of electrons, not protons?" means, because Electricity is a concept, not a real things, just like saying that gravity is made of mass, and relativity is made of light.
If they mean that both protons and electrons can form electric current, then see previous answer.

> Electrons are a kind of energy particle? Wrong.
>
> Electrons and protons are matter, not energy.

Electrons and protons are matter and not energy, photons are energy particles. However, when we talk to a 13 years old kid about transferring energy from the power station to their home, then saying that the powerstation is providing energy in the form of a current that moves electrons, it's a completely reasonable simplification.

> "Electricity" carries zero mass because electrons have little mass? No.
>
> Quantities of "Electricity" (meaning charge) have weight because charge is part of matter particles

The only thing I have to say is WTF?!, electrons have mass, and so do protons, but charge is a property, it doesn't "carry mass" it's like saying that because things have length and color, then "length carries a color". There are 2 types of particles that have charge: [leptons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton) ([electron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron), [muon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon) and [tau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tau_%28particle%29)) and [quarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark), each of those particles has mass and charge, but charge and mass are properties of the particle, not a particle by itself (protons and neutrons are made of quarks). This is particle physics material.

If the meaning is that electrons have no mass, then yes, they don't have mass. Electrons have ~10^3 less mass than a proton, for all practical purposes, an electron doesn't contribute any mass to the mass of the atom. Since, again, we are talking with kids, and we don't calculate the mobility of different materials (Solid state physics), or about movement of individual electrons (Quantum Physics), then the approximation that electrons have no mass is good enough.

> Positive charge is really just a loss of electrons? Wrong.
>
> Positive charge is not made of "missing electrons." Positive charge is a genuine type of charge in its own right.

True, a proton has a positive charge by itself. However since most subjects in nature come with a neutral charge, then in order to have a positive one you will need to take a way a negative charge (electron) and get an Ionized atom with a positive charge. Since kids are taught what is in nature, and nature doesn't have free positive charge without taking away an electron, again, acceptable.

> Positive charge cannot flow? Totally wrong.
>
> Electric currents in a metal wire are flows of electrons, but in many other materials both the positive and negative charges can flow

Positive charged particles, i.e. protons **can't** flow inside a solid matter, only electrons can, in some instances, we will say that there are "holes" that hold a positive charge and they are flowing inside a material, but holes are but a real particle, only a representation for a lack of electrons, protons don't move from their place inside a solid (they can vibrate in place). See first point.

> To create "static" charge, we transfer the electrons? Not always.
>
> "Static" or imbalanced charges can be created by removing electrons from a neutral atom.

On the first sentence they say "To create "static" charge, we transfer the electrons" but then they say "created by removing electrons from a neutral atom", which is the same as transferring an electron. You will get static charge if you just "remove" the electron, but the electron has to go somewhere.

> THE "ELECTRICITY" INSIDE OF WIRES MOVES AT THE SPEED OF LIGHT? Wrong.
>
> In metals, electric current is a flow of electrons. Many books claim that these electrons flow at the speed of light. This is incorrect. Electrons in an electric current actually flow quite slowly, at speeds on the order of centimeters per minute.

Electricity doesn't move at the speed of light, only light (photons) moves at the speed of light, and the speed of light changes in different materials. This is the only point where I agree with the source. While electrons move at very high speeds, the "current" is their drift speed, which is much slower (I don't know if they are right as to the speed is several cm per sec, but it changes with the magnitude of the applied field, so obviously, the current speed will change, whether you apply 1.5V of 1e5V on the conductor). If there is a text book saying that electrons move at speeds close to the speed of light without saying that the current doesn't flow at that speed, than that textbook is wrong.

Explanation on drift speed vs. speed:

Electrons move in random directions in very high speeds. When we talk about the current speed, we are talking about drift speed. The electron moves in different random directions inside the material, then collides with another particle, loses all it's speed and starts moving in a new random direction. When an electric field is applied, then the electron will move slightly more to a single direction, and thus drift in that direction. This is also why the current speed and not acceleration is relative to the force applied. [A good video explaining this subject](http://youtube.com/watch?v=TfIUI-bVbus)

**Final conclusion:**

What we have here is a post (and I would even go so far as call it a rant) that kids smaller than 14 aren't taught university undergraduate and graduate level physics, with all the fine nuances. While in some cases the source may have merit and a viable point if it was addressing that non-physics students (like EE, CS, MEC and others) are taught over simplified physics, the source doesn't address them, but, instead addresses small children in elementary school. Even if to claim that this is addressed to grown people who don't work at physics related jobs, or have physics related occupations would be, it would still be way too petty, as people who don't need the exact details, could be left very well with a basic understanding of the subject.

You can't explain physics at the level that the source demands without a lot of time being spent at explaining and learning all the subjects that are needed for a full and real understanding, including high level math, basic (university basic = high-school advanced) chemistry, and the physics that is at the core of those laws, including, particle physics, relativity theory, quantum mechanics, statistical physics, thermodynamics, EM theory and maybe even more, go to any college or university web site, look at the list of courses needed to be taken by students before they take the solid state physics course, this all you need to know to understand, why certain particles can conduct in certain material and other in other materials.

Because a full explanation is a very very very long and hard explanation, it's better to leave people and especially kids with some basic knowledge of the principals behind the phenomenons that they see every day, than to leave then with no explanation at all.

You can see from the source material at the undergraduate level that I provide here, that all those nuances and fine details are taught to students that learn the subject at the university, and that there isn't a fear of a physicist who thinks that protons don't have a charge associated with them.

Sources for other subjects touched on here:

Particle physics: No course book, but you can see a full Stanford course on this subject on [You Tube](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=F363FFF951EC0673)

Semiconductors and Solid State Physics: [Solid State Physics /Ashcroft & Mermin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0030839939)

*- Electromagnetic theory also knows to deal with magnetic currents, i.e. the displacement of magnetic charge. But since magnetic charge carriers were never found in nature, this is a purely theoretical aspect of the EM theory.

Comment: I just took part of the claims to not make the question too long, if you have any misunderstandings, read the homepage all the questions comes from, they explain details further.

Comment: Also I was taught that electrons almost moves at the speed of light and that it is as fast as the speed of light depending on material, and with that that electricity moves (almost) at the speed of light.

Comment: @Wertilq, you were taught right, but electrons move in random directions. When we talk about the current speed, we are talking about drift speed. The electron moves in different random directions inside the material, then collides with another particle, loses all it's speed and starts moving in a new random direction. When an electric field is applied, then the electron will move slightly more to a single direction, and thus drift in that direction. This is also why the current speed and not acceleration is relative to the force applied. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfIUI-bVbus

Comment: At the risk of making this close to unanswerable, your first paragraph (and sentences sprinkled throughout) are anecdotes and are not acceptable. Just because you were taught correctly, doesn't mean all/most people were. Just because you were taught the correct thing in your BSc doesn't mean 5-11 year olds are, as in the original claim.

Comment: @Oddthinking, I thought that he was talking about high school, not 5-11 years old kids. Now that I realize it, I'll rephrase the first paragraph to reflect this.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed You should also not just try to debunk my quotes, but instead go to homepage, and read the FULL quotes, especially the ones you said was untrue, and the ones you was confused by.

Comment: @Wertilq, I went to the site now, and it's filled with even more wrong statements. However, even the author always says, that is metals, the claims that they call wrong, are infact right. For some strange reason, they demand, that 13 years old kids be taught at the same level as University students.

Comment: I have heard a bit of conflicting claims now, a friend that knows a bit of electric theory, and have studied quantum physics quite a bit, said that what was said on the site was correct, and what you said in your answer was off. Is your answers based on the book, or how you remember/understood the book?

Comment: Mainly what I remember, but some of that stuff I learned this last semester, what is the part that he said was off? Maybe I wasn't clear on some points.

Comment: "Protons are ionized hydrogen atoms, so when there is a
                    flow of protons, it's not electric current but is called
                    plasma. And most importantly, protons, or ions can't flow
                    inside of another solid material (Solid state material)." He said that part was outright wrong. I have no clue who of you is correct, but neither he or I recognized part of what you was talking about, mainly the part about holes etc. :P

Comment: On positive charge flow, often in biological modeling you actually have positive ion flow, but it is really semantics.

Comment: A hole is a conceptual construct that represents the lack of an electron in an atom, which causes that atom to have positive charge. If you create a field in one direction, then the electrons will move in the opposite direction, so than the lack of electron will "move" to the direction of the field. There isn't a real hole it's just a construct. For example, if you have 20 people, and they have 19 apples, which they pass along, it's either to follow the missing apple, than the 19 apples, so you fallow the "apple hole", you can read more at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_hole

Comment: Almost all your objections are differences in style, except the "current is carried by electrons" is right in the source and your counter is wrong.  Appropriate solids can conduct protons also (e.g. ice), and you completely neglected liquids.  This is kind of important since the majority of current in your nervous system is moving sodium and potassium ions.  (I'm not sure if there are any practical instances of positive static electricity.)  So this doesn't make for a good answer.

Comment: A hydrogen atom is a proton and an electron, an Ionized hydrogen atom (i.e. the same atom without the electron) is a proton. You can have a flow of protons, or even Ionized atoms, but you can't have it in a solid material. In a solid material conductance is made by the free electrons in the substance. Only in liquids and gases an electric flow is possible through Ions (which don't have to be with a positive charge). Since, again, we are talking about children and electric (solid) wires, Ions are irrelevant. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_conductivity

Comment: @RexKerr, Ice can't conduct by moving protons, if the protons are moving, it's not a solid, if you have seen it, it must be that the ice that melted and became water was able to move Ions. The nervous system is not taught to children in the 6th grade, I didn't say that there isn't conductance through Ions, I said that in solids there isn't conductance through Ions, and that children are taught about electricity in wires.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed - The original claim said nothing about wires.  Electrons are the conductor in metals.  Also, I don't think water is a liquid at 130K, and: http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2008/CP/b807730b

Comment: @RexKerr, The original claim talked about children aged 6-13, see the second paragraph in my answer, as to why I assume why we only talk about metal conductors, i.e. solid state physics. As to the experiment that you cite, it doesn't apply any electrical field on the protons, so there isn't any electric current there.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed - In that case, your whole post is just making different assumptions than the "electric misconceptions" site--just explaining why these misconceptions aren't so bad if you don't know very much about electricity and related phenomena.

Comment: "so when there is a flow of protons, it's not electric current"  Yes it is.

Comment: @RexKerr, I'm sorry, you were right regarding the conductance of Ions in solids.

Comment: Your answer is very well constructed, but you only have references on the correctness part, and partially it's just your own reasoning. I don't really like your tone, you're not trying to objectively examine the site, and evaluate what it says, and you don't have any references on the teaching part. You more or less assume teaching kids 'wrong' is the only way, because the topic is too complex. Personally I think you're underestimating the kids, but if you can show me it's not possible to teach them less misconceptions, I am idle ears.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that "speed of electricity" is the same thing as drift speed of electrons. Fact is, that electricity propagates in copper wire at 97% speed of light. It propagates as electromagnetic wave, but that's way more advanced topic than K-6 curriculum. So teaching kids that **electricity** (not electrons) travels at speed of light isn't that big of a misconception.

Answer (score 8):

> **Is the theory commonly taught in school, as untrue as the page claims?**

This may be slightly fuzzy because it has been many years. However, when I was in school (high school and some electrical engineering) we learned that:

- electrical charge was transfer (build-up) of electrons.
- Protons are part of the atoms and when there are a lack of electrons
  you have a positive charge.
- Electric current is the flow of electrons and measured in Amperes
  (Coulombs/second).
- Electricity can flow through non-metals in different ways like Ions in water

He almost seems to be saying most of this is wrong. But then goes on to explain that it is not wrong, but there is more to it.

For example, from the website:

> ***ELECTRICITY IS MADE OF ELECTRONS? Wrong.**
>   Other things flow besides electrons. It's true that electric current in metals is a flow of electrons.*

The key word in this is `*in metals.*` So really, what we are taught in school wasn't incorrect but applies to the electricity we typically use and study, which is circuits consisting of metallic conductors.

Even the [Wikipedia article on Amperes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere) (measure of electric current) states the units in electrons per second:

> *In practical terms, the ampere is a measure of the amount of electric
>   charge passing a point in an electric circuit per unit time with
>   **6.241 × 10^18 electrons**, or one coulomb **per second** constituting one ampere.*

What we are taught is not *incorrect*, I think it is just *incomplete* i.e. oversimplified as you said. You can go into more specialised studies and expand upon the things you learned previously.

**So to answer your question, from the little I have been reading through the site it seems the site is correct. Just misleading at first, telling everyone they are "wrong", when really what they were taught is just "oversimplified".**

There is nothing ground-breaking in this site and he almost seems like someone ranting against the education system for not teaching elementary grade children advanced topics of study (high school and university).

My wife teaches grade K/1. Everything is very oversimplified. Teaching them how to measure is basically "Is this bigger than this?" No units or anything... Every step you learn is probably easy to think "this is all there is to it" until you get to the next level... it's human nature to be curious about everything, but also I find human nature to think you know everything about a subject once you learn a little about it. It's not until you really get into it that you find out you know nothing.

Comment: You didn't really answer whole the question. I appreciate someone else coming with their experience from school and what was taught, it is half the question. So at university you was taught what the home page went against? If so, do you know which of them is true, what was taught in your school, or the claims of the home page?

Comment: well the home page says things like "Other things flow besides electrons. It's true that electric current in *metals* is a flow of electrons. " So really, what I was taught wasn't incorrect but applies to the electricity we typically use and study, which is circuits consisting of metallic conductors.

Comment: Yea the claims on the homepage is more or less, "current study is oversimplified". For many purposes the details doesn't matter, but I am curious if the page is correct or not. Also you missed a number when you typed in when you graduated.

Comment: From what I am reading it seems the site is correct. Just misleading at first, telling everyone they are "wrong", when really just "oversimplified". In chemistry I vaguely remember electricity needing transfer of ions if transferring through water for example. So that is another case where it is not "a flow of electrons".

Comment: "he seems like someone ranting against the education system for not teaching elementary grade children advanced topics of study" To me it more felt like he was ranting at them making it sound like it was complete. Like not saying it's oversimplified. I personally found much of what was said that fairly big clash to what I had been taught, but that it still was 'sound'.

Comment: My wife teaches grade K/1. Everything is very oversimplified. Teaching them how to measure is basically "Is this bigger than this?" No units or anything... Every step you learn is probably easy to think "this is all there is to it" until you get to the next level... it's human nature to be curious about everything, but also I find human nature to think you know everything about a subject once you learn a little about it. It's not until you really get into it that you find out you know nothing.

Comment: I remade the question slightly, since I was unsatisfied with the question, and I the question was just too big, and I didn't make what I asked clear. The two things I am mainly interested in is the correctness of the site, and if teaching misconceptions is the right way. Do you have any references on teaching misconceptions? I like what you write, and the part about what your wife teach her students is interesting, but for validity, references about it would be appreciated.